# Slick query filter acting on arbitrary columns

Tags: scala, slick

Say I have a SQL table with columns `x` and `y`, each integer valued. I can do a Slick query to select for `5 <= x <= 10` like this:

```
val myQuery = TableQuery[MyXYTable]
myQuery.filter(p => p.x >= 5 && p.x <= 10)
```

Now suppose I want to simultaneously filter for `5 <= y <= 10` as well. I'd like to re-use my same filter logic, but this time apply it to the `y` column. Is there a way to do this in Slick? ie to write a filter function, and pass in an argument specifying which column it should filter? So I'd have something like:

```
myQuery.addFiveTenFilter(x-column).addFiveTenFilter(y-column)
```

If I was writing raw SQL this would be pretty trivial, but I can't see how to do it with Slick syntax.

Answer (score 1):

If you create a function of type `Rep[Int] => Rep[Boolean]`, you can use it in a `filter` method and pass the column in:

```
// As a function literal.
val filterByFiveTen: (Rep[Int] => Rep[Boolean]) = { column =>
  column >= 5 && column <= 10
}
myQuery.filter(row => filterByFiveTen(row.xColumn))

// As a method.
def filterByFiveTen(column: Rep[Int]): Rep[Boolean] = {
  column >= 5 && column <= 10
}
myQuery.filter(row => filterByFiveTen(row.xColumn))
```